using a variable which has content separated by spaces in shell in a for loop
I am trying to read a variable with spaces on prompt and trying to use in a for loop.,
For example:
Enter the items to read separated by space...  
apple orange kiwi  

read items  

for i in "$items"  
do  
echo $i  
...(additional operations)....  
done  

But shell does take the first item - apple here. What am I missing here.

What shell are you using, bash?  With what you have, I'd expect your loop to run once, and the value of $i to be "apple orange kiwi".  Try removing the quotes from "$items" and see if that gets you closer to what you're expecting.

remove the double quotes around the $items:
items="apple orange kiwi"

for i in $items
do
  echo $i
done

double-quotes in bash are a way to designate "this is one string, treat it as such" so when you do for i in "$items" it expands $items and becomes "apple orange kiwi" but for in bash by default takes multiple strings and loops over them.
That is also why the initial items definition needs double quotes: variable definition in bash takes a single string, not multiple

Unfortunately this does not work and it shows up like "apple when it prints.,
Only the first string is used

@sabarishtr  Works fine for me. I suspect you may using an editor that makes double quotes into the Unicode "LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK", which shell will not recognise as ASCII quotes.

@sabarishtr yea try another editor. Maybe kate?
